# Parse Js cloud code: how to access object's field

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Please look at this code where I indicate the problem with the HERE comment.
I try to access the field "shield" from joker object but I can't.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("decrementJokerCounter", function(request, response) {

var query = new Parse.Query("Jokers");
query.equalTo("userId", request.params.userId);
query.first({
  success: function(joker) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    if joker("shield") > 5 { // HERE
        joker.increment("shield", -1);
    }
    joker.save().then(function(){
          response.success("Joker counter decremented");
     });

  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    response.error("Could not decrement counter");
  }
});
});
```

joker("shield") > 5 is not accepted by the parse compiler but I don't have a specific error message. Do you know the proper syntax so I can get value of shield field ?

Comment: You Tried if( joker.get('shield') > 5 ){}

Comment: that works you can post it as an answer thanks

Comment: My Pleasure :). Please mark my answer as approved if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try

> if( joker.get('shield') > 5 ){ // HERE
>
> joker.increment("shield", -1);
>
> }